# Flashback, backup, checkpoint, redo logs

Tags: database, oracle, backup, flashback

I was searching over the internet to find good explanations of flashback, backup and checkpoint, but I find it hard to understand the difference.

Both flashback and backup can revert database to the previous state. Flashback can fix logical failures, but not physical failures.

Redo logs - store all changes made to the database, used to apply changes since latest backup

Checkpoint - when we update database, physical files aren't updated right away, but all changes are saved in redo logs to improve performance. Checkpoints are points when those changes are flushed to the database.

Sorry for my bad English. Could somebody explain those terms in more details ?

Comment: There are half a dozen or so technologies in Oracle that use the term "flashback" but which use very different implementations under the covers (and pull information from very different places).  Can you narrow down which flashback technology you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Oracle DBA concepts` on the internet to find many helpful documents.

For example, here is a link to a .pdf that does a good job of explaing Oracle concepts:

[Oracle Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540.pdf)

NOTE: links don't always stay valid, of course, so go ahead and download the .pdf file and see if that helps.